# Wordpress обработка шорткода на главной

Tags: wordpress

Как обработать шордкод в списке постов? В самой записи шорткод работает. А вот на главной странице, в "коротких записях" не хочет.

Answer (score 0):

Если под "короткими записями" имеется ввиду вывод через the_excerpt(), то нужно включить данную поддержку, например в файле темы functions.php:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

Comment: Ещё бы немного пояснений, что именно делает этот код...

Comment: Включает поддержку шорткодов.

Comment: Результат вы уже описали в ответе. А что делает каждая из команд, и почему нужны они обе?